# I'm trying to retrieve data from qSQL database

Tags: c++, sql, qt

But it does not get the data from the database. I'm do not want to retrieve the data to the table and want to display data in particular line edit. What is the error? Is there any modification?

This is the Code that I'm using:

```
void Userdetails::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    delete ui;

    // database connection
    database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    database.setHostName("localhost");
    database.setUserName("root");
    database.setPassword("");
    database.setDatabaseName("electricity");

    if(database.open()) {
         QSqlQuery qry;

         QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("MyConnect"));

         query.prepare(QString("SELECT accno, fullname, address, telephone FROM user_reg_elec WHERE username = :username AND password = :password"));

         if(query.exec()) {
             query.exec();

             while(query.next()) {
                 ui ->dislayaccountnumber ->setText(query.value(0).toString());
                 ui ->displayname ->setText(query.value(3).toString());
                 ui ->displayaddress ->setText(query.value(4).toString());
                 ui ->displattelephoneno ->setText(query.value(5).toString());
                 // ui ->displayamountoebill ->setText(query.value(6).toString());
             }
         } else {
               QMessageBox::information(this, "Query did not execute", "Not successful executing the query");
         }
    } else {
         QMessageBox::information(this, "Database not open", "Not opened successfully");
    }

    database.close();
}
```

Comment: `querry.prepare(QString("SELECT accno, fullname, address, telephone FROM user_reg_elec WHERE username = :username AND password = :password"));` Did you add the values for the parameterized query and just forget to add that code to your question? i donr see a bindValue in your code for the 2 parameters: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values)

Comment: @drescherjm i didn't fogot. this is tha all. Can you explain mutch?

Comment: The linked documentation shows you how. querry.bindValue("::username", "Bart");

Comment: Did you really want the user to have to search by username and password? Do you ask both of these in your GUI?

Comment: Also I assume there will only be 1 record with the same username and password so the `while(querry.next()) {` will probably loop 1 or 0 times.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it

Comment: @GeoTech change to `QSqlQuery query(database);`

Comment: Is there any other thing? Even after modifications,data does not load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has four main issues:

1. You have deleted the `ui` at the beginning of your code. Hence, the first line that calls `ui->` will crash the program.
2. You have defined your query improperly. Also, your way to select a name for your connection is not right.
3. You have executed your query twice (one is enough).
4. You've not bind values for `username` and `password`.

Please use the following:

```
void Userdetails::on_pushButton_4_clicked() {

    {
        // database connection
        QSqlDatabase database;
        database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL","MyConnect");
        database.setHostName("localhost");
        database.setUserName("root");
        database.setPassword("");
        database.setDatabaseName("electricity");

        if(database.open()) {

            QSqlQuery query(database);


            if (query.prepare(QString("SELECT accno, fullname, address, telephone FROM user_reg_elec WHERE username = :username AND password = :password"))) {

                //Add bindings
                query.bindValue(":username","your user name");
                query.bindValue(":password","your password");
                if(query.exec()) {

                    while(query.next()) {
                        ui ->dislayaccountnumber ->setText(query.value(0).toString());
                        ui ->displayname ->setText(query.value(1).toString());
                        ui ->displayaddress ->setText(query.value(2).toString());
                        ui ->displattelephoneno ->setText(query.value(3).toString());
                        // ui ->displayamountoebill ->setText(query.value(4).toString());
                    }
                } else {
                    qDebug() << "Query did not execute due to: " << query.lastError().text();
                    QMessageBox::information(this, "Query did not execute", "Not successful executing the query");
                }
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Query not prepared due to the following error: " << query.lastError().text();
            }
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Database not opened due to: " << database.lastError().text();
            QMessageBox::information(this, "Database not open", "Not opened successfully");
        }

        database.close();
    }

    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("MyConnect");
}
```

Please add `#include <QSqlError>` to the top, if you have not already included this library.

**Only to the questionary:**

To show details in a new window, after you got the target user's information from your database, you can create a new dialog (window) and show the results in it as follows:

```
    //Create a new dialog
    QDialog *dialog = new QDialog;

    //Add some elements to the dialog
    QLabel *accountNumber = new QLabel("Account number: " + query.value(0).toString());
    QLabel *name = new QLabel("Name: " + query.value(1).toString());
    QLabel *address = new QLabel("Address: " + query.value(2).toString());
    QLabel *phoneNumber = new QLabel("Phone number: " + query.value(3).toString());
    QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout;
    lay->addWidget(accountNumber);
    lay->addWidget(name);
    lay->addWidget(address);
    lay->addWidget(phoneNumber);
    dialog->setLayout(lay);

    //Show the dialog
    dialog->open();
```

Comment: No no. It is a typo mistake. I forgot to delete it. I edited my answer.

Comment: How can I modify this, for using separate windows for login and  show user details?

Comment: Would you please give more details about your question? Let me know what exactly you want to do.

Comment: After login, the user details display in the new window according to the username and password.

Comment: If I've understand you right, you can delete the ```WHERE``` condition from your query and select all user names and passwords: ```SELECT accno, fullname, address, telephone FROM user_reg_elec;``` and then in your ```While``` loop store data in some arrays and then display all of them in a [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) or [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html).

Comment: I want to display user details according to the username and password that user used to log in he system. Not all users details. Any idea?

Comment: You mean you want to show details in a new window? I mean, your question is how to show details in a new window (and not the current window)?

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation. I'm try to make a Login as a one window. After enter the user name and password, it's open new window named userdetails. In that userdetails window, should display the user details already stored in MYSQL database.

Comment: No problem :). Your current code gets  a user name and password pair and finds the corresponding details in your MySQL database and writes them in ```ui ->dislayaccountnumber```, ```ui ->displayname```,```ui ->displayaddress```, and ``` ui ->displattelephoneno```. Now, you want to show these items in a **new window***. Ok?

Comment: Ok. Please see the **Only for the questionary** section I added to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.